# tkinter Buttons not calling functions

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a beginner programmer trying to create a program that allows the user to player Rock, Paper, Scissors using tkinter. I haven't learned tkinter in class, but this is my final project, so I was trying to learn something new to impress.

I was able to figure out how to position everything, but my buttons don't seem to do anything. The quit button works, but not anything else. There are no interpreter errors that come up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random

def get_computer_hand(): #Picks computer's hand.

pick = random.randint(1,3) #Randomly chooses a number between 1 and 3.

if pick == 1:
    hand = "Rock"

elif pick == 2:
    hand = "Paper"

elif pick == 3:
    hand = "Scissors"

return hand

def setRock():
global playerHand
global computerHand

playerHand = "Rock"
computerHand = get_computer_hand()
runGame(playerHand,computerHand)

def setPaper():
global playerHand
global computerHand

playerHand = "Paper"
computerHand = get_computer_hand()

runGame(playerHand,computerHand)

def setScissors():
global playerHand
global computerHand

playerHand = "Scissors"
computerHand = get_computer_hand()
runGame(playerHand,computerHand)

def setQuit():
root.destroy()

def runGame(player,computer):

global playerWins
global computerWins
global draws
global win_or_loss

playerHand = player
computerHand = computer

if(player == "Rock"):

    if(computer == "Paper"):
        computerWins += 1
        win_or_loss = "Paper beats Rock. You lose!"

    elif(computer == "Scissors"):
       playerWins += 1
       win_or_loss = "Rock beats Scissors. You win!"

    else:
        draws += 1
        win_or_loss = "Draw!"

if(player == "Paper"):

    if(computer == "Rock"):
        playerWins += 1
        win_or_loss = "Paper beats Rock. You win!"

    elif(computer == "Scissors"):
        computerWins += 1
        win_or_loss = "Paper beats Rock. You win!"

    else:
        draws += 1
        win_or_loss = "Draw!"

if(player == "Scissors"):

    if(computer == "Rock"):
        computerWins += 1
        win_or_loss = "Rock beats Scissors. You lose!"

    elif(computer == "Paper"):
        playerWins += 1
        win_or_loss = "Scissors beats Paper. You win!"

    else:
        draws += 1
        win_or_loss = "Draw!"

root = Tk()
root.title("Rock Paper Scissors")

playerWins = 0
computerWins = 0
draws = 0
playerHand = ""
computerHand = ""
win_or_loss = ""

mainFrame = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainFrame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

buttonFrame = ttk.Frame(mainFrame)
handFrame = ttk.Frame(mainFrame)

ttk.Label(mainFrame, text="Let's play Rock, Paper, Scissors.         Ready?").grid(column=0,row=0)

rockButton = ttk.Button(buttonFrame, text="Rock", command = setRock)
paperButton = ttk.Button(buttonFrame, text="Paper", command = setPaper)
scissorsButton = ttk.Button(buttonFrame, text="Scissors", command = setScissors)
quitButton = ttk.Button(buttonFrame, text="Quit", command = setQuit)

rockButton.pack(side="left",fill=None,expand=False)
paperButton.pack(side="left",fill=None,expand=False)
scissorsButton.pack(side="left",fill=None,expand=False)
quitButton.pack(side="left",fill=None,expand=False)
buttonFrame.grid(column=0,row=1)

playerHandLabel = ttk.Label(handFrame, text="You picked: " + playerHand)
computerHandLabel = ttk.Label(handFrame, text="Computer picked: " +         computerHand)
playerHandLabel.pack(side="left",fill=None,expand=False)
computerHandLabel.pack(side="left",fill=None,expand=False)
handFrame.grid(column=0,row=2)

winOrLoss = ttk.Label(mainFrame, text=win_or_loss).grid(column=0,row=3)

ttk.Label(mainFrame, text = "Player Wins: " +         str(playerWins)).grid(column=0,row=4)
ttk.Label(mainFrame, text = "Computer Wins: " +         str(computerWins)).grid(column=0,row=5)
ttk.Label(mainFrame, text = "Draws: " + str(draws)).grid(column=0,row=6)

for child in mainFrame.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The buttons do work, they just don't give you any visual feedback. They set the `playerWins` and `win_or_loss` variables, but they don't update the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

The display does not change because to change the text of the label `winOrLoss` you need to do: `winOrLoss.configure(text=win_or_loss)`, just changing `win_or_loss` won't change the label content.

Another possibility is to use a StringVar:

```
win_or_loss = StringVar()
winOrLoss = Label(textvariable=win_or_loss)
```

and then, to change the label content, you do `win_or_loss.set("new string")`.